# Enmascarar Urls

Tags: pretty-urls

Estoy iniciandome en el mundilllo y llevo varias semanas intentando hacer varias cosas con mis Urls:

1ª Quitar la extensión de mi página de inicio index.php

https://misitio.com/**index.php**

2ª quitar los .html y .php

Hay mucha cantidad de info en la web y más que aclarar me hice un lío.

Especifico que sí he conseguido limpiarlas mediante renombrar esto que no sé muy bien lo que es pero me parece que es donde se hacen las llamadas (¿el menú de cabecera de cada página? o algo de eso):

Inicio

Servicios

....

Simplemente le quito la extensión .php y .html a todos los archivos y con una directriz en el .htaccess para que me reconozca las urls sin estas extensiones ya me permite hacerlo.

Pero pierdo demasiado tiempo en tocar todo el código de cada una de las páginas continuamente... necesito una regla universal que me evite haer esto en el archivo. Aclaro que uso un editor de tipo wysiwyg y que al hacer cualquier modificación y subir los archivos me lo sube con las extensiones .php y .html (y una vez subidas al servidor tengo que modificarlas ahí mismo).

Mi pregunta es: Hay algún código para que el htcaccess oculte cualquier index.php de la página de inicio y cualquier extensión de archivo .php o .html de cualquier web de las que alojo en mi public_html? Algo así como una directriz general.

Chicos necesito ayuda, soy un parado de larga duración con familia y estoy peleando como gato panza arrriba para salir de la crisos, así que estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta por que no tengo dinero para pagar ningún curso ni a ningún programador. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceré enormemente (por que otra cosa no tengo). Muchísimas gracias de antemano a cualquiera que tienda su mano.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás empezando, el uso de "pretty-urls" es complicado, lo que te expondré a continuación hará falta pulirlo para que sea 100% funcional y también adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Lo ideal es que toda tu web cargue desde ***index.php*** y que sea este el que se encargue de "incluir" el contenido que se va a mostrar en el sitio. Hay frameworks que hacen todo esto por ti como laravel o codeigniter.

Lo primero es redirigir todas las peticiones a index.php, esto lo hacemos con estas lineas de código en .htaccess también indicaremos a que sección quiere acceder el usuario, para poderlo usar más tarde desde PHP, para hacer eso usaremos "$_GET".

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Lo siguiente es distribuir esas peticiones según lo que el usuario requiera. Crea una carpeta llamada contenido e introduce ahí tus archivos, por ejemplo:

- contenido/contacto.php
- contenido/productos.php
- contenido/quienes-somos.php
- contenido/principal.php

**index.php**

```
//En la variable $action almacenamos el apartado que debemos mostrar.
$action = $_GET['action'];


//Si el usuario no introduce ninguna acción (apartado), se mostrará la página principal.
if($_GET['action']==NULL){
$action = 'principal';
}

//Comprobamos si el archivo a mostrar existe.
if(file_exists('contenido/'.$action.'Controller.php')){

//Incluimos dicha página
    require 'contenido/'.$action.'.php';

}
```

Como ya he dicho anteriormente, este código no es 100% ideal, pero si es la base de todo. Puedes investigar más sobre frameworks en php y sobre el modelo MVC. Te deseo suerte con tus proyectos :).

Comment: Te agradezco muchísimo la respuesta, muy completa, lo voy a empezar a estudiar según los pasos que me has dado.